# How to cancel PostgreSQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I am not very familiar with databases or SQL and wanted to make sure that I don't mess anything up. I did:

```
SELECT pid, state, usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

To check if I had any queries and there were several that had the state active. Do I just cancel them by doing:

```
select pg_cancel_backend(PID);
```

And this won't affect anything except the my queries, correct? I also wanted to figure out why those queries were still in the state active. I have a python file where I read in my sql file, but I stopped running the python file in the middle of reading my sql file. Is that possibly why it happened and why the states are still active?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what `pg_cancel_backend(pid)` is for. Why exactly the query is still running depends on a few things - could be waiting to grab a lock, or the query could just take a long time - but given the python processes that started the queries have exited, the connection is technically already closed, the PG backend process just hasn't noticed yet. It won't notice until the query completes and it tries to return the query status to the client, at which point it'll rollback the transaction when it sees the connection is no longer present.

The only effect pg_cancel_backend on the PIDs of those backends should have is to cause PG to notice the connection is closed immediately, rather than whenever the query completes.